# WGS84-coordinate encoded as Integers

Tags: c#, integer, coordinate-system, floating-point, casting

I want to store WGS84-coordinates in two integers for latitude and longitude instead of floats to get a higher precision than with floats.

Here's my code:

```
struct Coordinate
{
    private int latitude;
    private int longitude;

    const double latMin = -90.0f;
    const double latMax = 90.0f;
    const double lngMin = -180.0f;
    const double lngMax = 180.0f;

    public Coordinate(double latitude, double longitude)
    {
        this.latitude = mapDoubleToInt(latitude, latMin, latMax);
        this.longitude = mapDoubleToInt(longitude, lngMin, lngMax);
    }

    public double Latitude { get { return mapIntToDouble(latitude, latMin, latMax); } }
    public double Longitude { get { return mapIntToDouble(longitude, lngMin, lngMax); } }

    private static int mapDoubleToInt(double value, double min, double max)
    {
        return (int)(((long)int.MaxValue - int.MinValue) * (value - min) / (max - min) + int.MinValue);
    }

    private static double mapIntToDouble(int value, double min, double max)
    {
        return ((double)value - int.MinValue) / ((long)int.MaxValue - int.MinValue) * (max - min) + min;
    }   
}
```

I'm not sure if there is a better to convert the data. There are a lot of casts and arithmetic operations in it -- any way to do this more elegantly?

Comment: You are using double not float.  If you want more precision just use decimal.

Comment: Decimals are horribly slow. :-(

Comment: Decimal are not that much slow than double and you are going through a lot of effort here.  You are going to need to cast a lot of the ints to decimal to not get integer math.

Comment: But decimal takes 12 bytes! I can't afford that. Otherwise I would use doubles straight away, but I can't even afford those eight bytes.

Comment: You should add that to the question

Answer (score 5):

you can avoid stuffing everything in a one-liner:

```
private static int mapDoubleToInt(double value, double min, double max)
{
    long intRange = 1L << 32; // ==((long)int.MaxValue - int.MinValue)
    double inputRange = max - min;
    return (int)(intRange * (value - min) / inputRange + int.MinValue);
}

private static double mapIntToDouble(int value, double min, double max)
{
    long intRange = 1L << 32; // ==((long)int.MaxValue - int.MinValue)
    double inputRange = max - min;
    return inputRange * ((double)value - int.MinValue) / intRange + min;
}
```

After reordering the operations it's now clearer that they are opposites. Especially after extracting the range as variables.

Comment: The recommendation on type suffixes are to use capitals so as not to confuse `l` with `1`.  Suggest using `1L` instead.

Comment: Is (1L << 32) really what I want as range or is it ((1L << 32) - 1)?

Comment: @user2033412 depends on whether max is inclusive or exclusive.

Comment: It's WGS84 coordinates -- I could make it exclusive by replacing +180° ⇒ −180°, you're right.